# In superGM tournaments are time management extensions forbidden?

Tags: rules, tournament, etiquette, cheating, chess.com

An extension was released in 2021Feb: [Hikaru and GothamChess Tell You to MOVE (Time Management Extension)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2zFAPYrMZo). After a certain amount of elapsed time, you get notified by a voice of Hikaru Nakamura or Levy Rozman.

I ask about this (for regular amateur games) here: [How isn't a time management extension cheating / unethical?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/45048/how-isnt-a-time-management-extension-cheating-unethical)

**Question**: In online superGM tournaments, such as Meltwater Champions Chess Tour, Rapid Chess Championship, Chess.com Global Championship, Speed Chess Championship, etc, are such time management extensions (even if they wouldn't help cf [Link1](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/11405/n00b-ethics-question-about-calculators-in-online-poker-or-choker). [Link2](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43505/would-a-board-for-calculating-non-blindfold-help-gms-in-slow-games/45052#45052)) like this cheating / unethical?

Comment: No top player has thought about using these so it's purely hypothetical